# conditonal infrastructrue changes with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to do some conditional changes in terraform.

```
    resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "war" {
  name                        = "${local.clSqlDatabaseName}-${var.environment}"
  server_id                   = jokes
  min_capacity                = 0.5
  max_size_gb                 = 100
  zone_redundant              = false
  collation                   = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
  sku_name                    = "GP_S_Gen5_2"
  auto_pause_delay_in_minutes = "${var.environment == "Prod" ? -1 : 60}"

  short_term_retention_policy {
   retention_days = 35
   }
```

auto_pause_delay_in_minutes is dependent on the environment variable == Prod and thats fair enough , but how do i make the short_term_retention_policy be dependent on the Prod variable too ?

Comment: hello @jason_hough, can you please give an example on how you want to make retention policy dependent on environment variable? like what is the requirement you are trying to do ?

Comment: Hi @AnsumanBal-MT - i am wanting to use the var.environment variable and if it is Prod then apply the block.. just like the auto_pause_retention_policy.

Comment: ohkay , so for the whole block I guess you can use dynamic condition block for retention policy .. let me try it and get back here

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT - great thanks !

Comment: I tested it and seems using a string variable , I can set the short term retention policy days to 7 if its not prod and 35 if prod.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to make the `short_term_retention_policy` [dynamic](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/mssql_database#short_term_retention_policy):

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "war" {
  name                        = "${local.clSqlDatabaseName}-${var.environment}"
  server_id                   = jokes
  min_capacity                = 0.5
  max_size_gb                 = 100
  zone_redundant              = false
  collation                   = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
  sku_name                    = "GP_S_Gen5_2"
  auto_pause_delay_in_minutes = "${var.environment == "Prod" ? -1 : 60}"

  dynamic "short_term_retention_policy" {
    for_each = var.environment == "Prod" ? [1] : []

    content {
      retention_days = 35
    }
  }
}
```

This `short_term_retention_policy` will be applied only if `var.environment` is  "Prod", otherwise it will be ignored.

Comment: Hello @ErvinSzilagyi, it sets the retention days to 7 if the environment is not prod .

Comment: If you don't apply set anything for the `retention_days` value, Terraform sets the default of `7`.